# Access variable of one subroutine into another subroutine -VB

Tags: vb.net

I have two questions

1. I want to use `result`in my `Button15_ click` sub
2. when i was typing in the line `op = sender.Text` ,I dint saw `Text` method of sender object in intellisense ?

Here is my code

```
Public Sub Button10_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button10.Click, Button11.Click, Button12.Click, Button13.Click, Button14.Click, Button14.Click, Button16.Click
    Dim op As Char
    op = sender.Text

     result = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text)

End Sub

Public Sub Button15_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button15.Click
    Select Case op
        Case "+"
            result += Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text)
            TextBox1.Text = result
        Case "-"
            result -= Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text)
            TextBox1.Text = result
        Case "*"
            result *= Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text)
            TextBox1.Text = result
        Case "\"
            result \= Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text)
            TextBox1.Text = result


    End Select




End Sub
```

Comment: `op` needs to be declared at the Class level in order for it to be used in multiple functions.

Answer (score 1):

Declare `op` as class-level:

```
Dim op As Char

Public Sub Button10_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button10.Click, Button11.Click, Button12.Click, Button13.Click, Button14.Click, Button14.Click, Button16.Click
    op = sender.Text

    result = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text)
End Sub

Public Sub Button15_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button15.Click
    Select Case op
        Case "+"
            result += Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text)
            TextBox1.Text = result
        Case "-"
            result -= Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text)
            TextBox1.Text = result
        Case "*"
            result *= Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text)
            TextBox1.Text = result
        Case "\"
            result \= Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text)
            TextBox1.Text = result
    End Select
End Sub
```

The reason you don't see `Text` in IntelliSense is that `sender` is an `Object`, not a `TextBox`, and does not have a `Text` property. I recommend that you turn on `Option Strict`, as it will reveal several potential code errors. To get it, cast `sender`:

```
op = DirectCast(sender, Button).Text(0)
```

There's also a lot of common logic in `Button15_Click`. I'd rewrite it as:

```
Dim rightOperand As Integer = Integer.Parse(TextBox1.Text)

Select Case op
    Case "+"c
        result += rightOperand
    Case "-"c
        result -= rightOperand
    Case "*"c
        result *= rightOperand
    Case "\"c
        result \= rightOperand
End Select

TextBox1.Text = result.ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private op as Char

Public Sub Button10_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button10.Click, Button11.Click, Button12.Click, Button13.Click, Button14.Click, Button14.Click, Button16.Click 
    op = DirectCast(sender, button).Text
     result = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text) 
End Sub
```